# Bitwise MySQL NAND query

Tags: mysql, bit-manipulation

I have a table of integers and I want to select all which , if converted to binary, do not have both bits 1 and 2 set.

Or, for another query, which do not have both bits 3 and 4 set.

For example, in a table having column name decvalue, with values ...

4
7
11
12
13
18
20
27

I would get 4, 12  and 20 as the result for the first selection
I would get 18 for the second selection.

I have no idea where to start on this, I tried...

```
foreach($db->query('SELECT   id, lineid, decvalue, dateupdated FROM      trialtable      WHERE decvalue 1!&2 ORDER BY id ASC') as $record)
{
id=$record['id'];
$dateupdated=$record['dateupdated'];
$decvalue=$record['decvalue']; 
echo $dateupdated." decvalue<br>";
}
```

Thanks and regards,

Graham

Comment: What do you mean "1-st bit is not set"?. If it's not set, then it's insignificant and should be truncated. I.e. in base 2 positive integer numbers will always have `1` as first bit. Are your numbers aligned somehow?

Comment: I should have qualified bit 1 = least significant. By that, I mean if the number were converted to binary, that bit would be 0. So, I am interested in numbers in my list which have neither bit 1 nor bit 2 set , for example 8 is binary 1000 so bits 1 and 2 are not set. However 7 is 111 and both bits 1 and 2 are set.

Comment: If you'll convert any number to base 2, your first bit will always be `1` - that's why I'm asking

Comment: Oh I see, no I mean bit 1 is least significant , value=1, bit 2=value 2, bit 3 = value4, bit 4 = value 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`id` int)
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`id`)
VALUES
    (4),
    (7),
    (11),
    (12),
    (13),
    (18),
    (20),
    (27)
;
```

---

```
select id, bin(id)
from t;

| ID | BIN(ID) |
|----|---------|
|  4 |     100 |
|  7 |     111 |
| 11 |    1011 |
| 12 |    1100 |
| 13 |    1101 |
| 18 |   10010 |
| 20 |   10100 |
| 27 |   11011 |
```

---

```
select 
id,
bin(id)
from t
where not(id & 1) = 1
and not(id & 2) = 2;


| ID | BIN(ID) |
|----|---------|
|  4 |     100 |
| 12 |    1100 |
| 20 |   10100 |
```

---

```
select 
id,
bin(id)
from t
where not(id & 4) = 4
and not(id & 8) = 8;


| ID | BIN(ID) |
|----|---------|
| 18 |   10010 |
```

Comment: Thanks FancyPants - but that is the AND operator, but I am looking to achieve NAND, so for the first example, I want only values where the right hand bits are 0, not 1.

Comment: Many thanks indeed - perfect! I tried to vote, but I'm too new for it to register.

Comment: But you can accept the answer by clicking the check below the vote buttons. Thanks ;)